# Cloudwatch figures in MySQL

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I want to know whether there is a way to use MySQL queries to obtain the same data that Cloudwatch shows on its dashboard.

CPUUtilization
DatabaseConnections
FreeStorageSpace
Freeable Memory

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.processlist; may have a number close to Cloudwatch Connections.

view profile, please.